# Redirection 301 in .htaccess not effective?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Came accross a strange bug that is starting to play on my nerves.

So I have a huge .htacces file with a lot of redirection which is actually working.

Im starting to think this file need to be compiled...

Those are examples of working one :

```
#redirection des liens morts 9/11/15

RedirectPermanent /rappel.html http://www.agencedevoyage.com
RedirectPermanent /mail.html http://www.agencedevoyage.com
```

And those one are not working.. Why is that ? Is it due to special characters ?

```
#redirection des liens morts 22/12/15

RedirectPermanent /voyage/asie/vi%C3%AAt-nam/ http://www.agencedevoyage.com/voyage/asie/vietnam/
RedirectPermanent /voyage/asie/viêt-nam/ http://www.agencedevoyage.com/voyage/asie/vietnam/
```

Any help gladly appreciate.

### Edit :

Half Solution

So I manage to do it by using this rule :

```
RedirectMatch 301 /voyage/asie/vi.*t-nam/?$ http://www.agencedevoyage.com/voyage/asie/vietnam/?continent=asie&country=vietnam&type=voyage
```

But this is clearly not really what I want since the idea was to minimise the number of link...

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules **at top** just below `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /voyage/asie/vi\%C3\%AAt-nam/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /voyage/asie/vietnam/? [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(rappel|mail)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Actually `AllowEncodedSlashes` helps for `%2F` etc but this should work without `AllowEncodedSlashes` enabled.

Comment: It send me to redirect me to `http://www.agencedevoyage.com/voyage/asie/vietnam/?continent=asie&country=vi%C3%AAt-nam&type=voyage`

Comment: Make sure to keep these rules right at the top before any other rules and test in a new browser.

Comment: @Starkeen and when I tried to put AllowEncodedSlashes I get error 500, I'm looking where shall I put it but I haven't find yet

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, looks like I need to **Reread** the manual :)

Comment: @anubhava Done both what you've said but it is still redirecting me to the page above.

Comment: So I edit my post since I manage to do it but I'm loosing the interest of the thing since it's for SEO..

Comment: Also the rule you're showing in latest edit is wrong as it exposes your internal URL to external clients and is not considered good for SEO.